# Any concerns with running a camper with a 15 amp connector

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac

I have a camper that I need to have power to for a couple of days. It has a 30amp 25ft cord for power which I want to plug into an adapter so it can plug into a regular wall socket. The connector is from camping world and is about 18 inches long and is a 30 amp to 15 amp connector. The outlet is on a 20 amp circuit. Everything seems to work and the breaker isn't tripping, mainly because I have nothing else on the circuit and am only running the AC and lights in the camper. My concern is that the outlet does get a little warm and I'm wondering if I should be concerned?  Could it get hot enough to melt or cause a fire without tripping the breaker? Anything else I should consider or do?

Please edit my tags if I tagged improperly. Im usually only active on Stackoverflow.  Thanks!

Here is an example of the connector

http://mobilehomepartsstore.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=201103&Store_Code=MHPS&gdffi=5a91c85c988a43159be79f03f721bc24&gdfms=3BD1A1DCA412425BACF279B7BD4E5C34&gclid=CO-RqNCGnM4CFQKTaQod3oIFBQ

Comment: The important question is why does the air conditioner draw (find the nameplateand tell us what it says) The converter cord is called 15 amp because the male plug is NEMA 5-15 and not NEMA 5-20.  (Most people have 5-15 and not 5-20 recpiticals at home, even when it's a 20 amp circuit)

Comment: Thanks @Tyson I'll check when I get home-- and thanks for the info on the connector. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Well @Tyson I can't get on the roof to check the panel due to the ladder being out of service but it is on a 20amp breaker in the RV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly common for RV and trailer owners to use a 30-15 amp adapter while they are stored, to power the on-board trickle charger for the battery, for lighting, and for the refrigerator.

The problem is when someone uses the AC and a combination of these other things. You may very well trip the breaker in your home panel, and/or end up with an adapter that looks like this:

[image]
The rule of thumb is that if you need to run the AC, run only the AC unless you have a 30 amp circuit for your un-adapted power cord.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I don't have the hot water heater, or refrigerator on and they will not be using the microwave so I feel like I should be good. They will only be in there at night

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a circuit that can deliver 20 amps and a cord rated for 15 amps.

That is technically inadequate, as your house could happily pump too much current through your 'skinny' 15 amp connection.

I suggest you find a better connector. (Especially since you mentioned AC... those are often power hungry.)

Comment: The wire to the outlet  from the breaker is rated 20 amp of course. From the outlet to the camper is the connector and cord which is 15 amp to 30 amp. The connector was created for the camper so I'm less worried about that in particular though I'm kind of baffled why it wasn't a 30 to 20 amp connector

Comment: Or maybe the description of the connector is misleading because it is pretty thick. As thick as the 30 amp wire?

Comment: @scsimon it's not 30 to 20 amp because then it would have a NEMA 5-20 plug on it.  This would prove to be frustrating as NEMA 5-20 receptacles are fairly rare.  Instead of looking like a face in horror, it looks like one who is winking.

Comment: Also I would suggest to look closely at the rating of his A/C.   Units have gotten impressively efficient in recent years, with 8000 BTU units pulling as little as 5 amps.  This is wonderful news for those of us powering A/C units through rickety wiring.

Comment: Hahahaha @Harper that description was awesome on the plug once I pictured what you were saying. I'll let you know the draw on the AC in an hour when I'm home.